# Access string from key value json response

Tags: java, android, json

I'm getting this simple json response and I can't access the value easily. The response is this

```
{"email":"ted@ted.com"}
```

That's after doing json.toString(). Now I'm trying to access the value of email and I keep getting errors. I thought it was just

```
json.getString("email")
```

Also this is in java.

edit: 
here are the errors I'm getting

```
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:867)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4066)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10193)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.widget.TextView.invalidateRegion(TextView.java:4375)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:4318)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:7172)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:8759)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:979)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:688)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:302)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3535)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at com.reflap.reflap.EditProfile$fillfields.doInBackground(EditProfile.java:61)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at com.reflap.reflap.EditProfile$fillfields.doInBackground(EditProfile.java:1)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-22 06:45:11.524: E/AndroidRuntime(9977):     ... 5 more
```

I'm doing this in a background process.

Comment: what errors you are getting?

Comment: I suggest you post your whole code for deserializing the json, as well as the json text itelf (unless it really only consists in `{"email":"ted@ted.com"}`). Also if you have any stack trace, that would help.

Comment: The json text is just {"email":"ted@ted.com"} That's it.

Comment: have you did this `JSONObject object = new JSONObject(" {"email":"ted@ted.com"} ");` before doing `json.getString("email")`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with te parsing of the json but that you are trying to manipulate a textview in a background thread. Do that in onPostExecute instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your stack trace is not caused by the parsing of the JSON data, but by the fact your `AsyncTask` is referencing the UI (some `TextView`) in the `doInBackground` method.

You would normally reference your views `onPostExecute`, possibly through `WeakReference` s.

Comment: ahh yeah, that might be it. Just a sec.